# Titanium - PHP+JSON error parsing

Tags: javascript, php, json, titanium, httpclient

I'm developing a simple app to log in into a panel, interacting with a Mysql DB.
In my app create an HTTP client to login or to register new users.

Into `index.js` i put the code about the log in, in the `newuser.js` i put the code about a registration.

I've created a HTTP client to register new users, in the `newuser.js`

```
createReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();


createReq.onload = function() {
Titanium.API.info("Start onload");
var jsonReg = this.responseText;
var resultReg = JSON.parse(jsonReg);
Titanium.API.info("Start IF");

if (resultReg.registered == false) {
    alert('utente esistente');
    $.view_indicator.hide();
    Titanium.API.info("user NOT registered");

    } else if(resultReg.registered == true) {
    alert('utente NON esistente');
    $.view_indicator.hide();
    Titanium.API.info("user registered");

    }

}



function createUser () {
if ( $.user.value != '' && $.pass.value != '' && $.pass_check.value != '' && $.name.value != '' && $.email.value != '' ) {

    if ($.pass.value != $.pass_check.value) {
        alert("Le password non coincidono.")
    } else {
        if (!check_email($.email.value)) {
            alert("Inserisci una email valida");
        } else {
            createReq.open("POST", "http://solimeo.sviluppofacile.it/register.php");
            var params = {
                username: $.user.value,
                password: Ti.Utils.md5HexDigest($.pass.value),
                name: $.name.value,
                email: $.email.value
            };
            $.view_indicator.show();
            createReq.send(params);
        };
        $.user.blur();
        $.pass.blur();
        $.pass_check.blur();
        $.name.blur();
        $.email.blur();
    };

} else {
    alert("Tutti i campi sono obbligatori!");
};

}
```

JSON data in this case, came from this PHP page, `register.php`

```
<?php

include ('connection.php');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "SELECT username,email FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username . "' OR email = '" . $email . "'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {

$response = array('registered' => false, 'message' => 'Utente che esiste');

echo json_encode($response);

} else {

$insert = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,name,email) VALUES ('" . $username . "','" . $password . "','" . $name . "','" . $email . "')";
$query  = mysql_query($insert);

if ($query) {
    //echo "Utente correttamente registrato! Puoi ora loggarti.";
$response = array('registered' => true, 'message' => 'Utente correttamente registrato! Puoi ora loggarti.');
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    //echo "Registrazione fallita";
$response = array('registered' => false, 'message' => 'Registrazione fallita.');
echo json_encode($response);
}
}

mysql_close($connect) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

But if i try to register a user that exists yet, i've this error

```
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at undefined:1: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
[ERROR] :  XMLModule: (KrollRuntimeThread) [46894,49752] Error parsing XML
[ERROR] :  XMLModule: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT {"registered":fa...@2:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@429a8648)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at ti.modules.titanium.xml.XMLModule.parse(XMLModule.java:82)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at ti.modules.titanium.xml.XMLModule.parse(XMLModule.java:68)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient.getResponseXML(TiHTTPClient.java:700)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at ti.modules.titanium.network.HTTPClientProxy.getResponseXML(HTTPClientProxy.java:107)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeCallProperty(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.callProperty(V8Object.java:73)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1121)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
[ERROR] :  XMLModule:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:112)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: (KrollRuntimeThread) [1,49753] Error parsing XML
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT {"registered":fa...@2:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@429a8648)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.xml.XMLModule.parse(XMLModule.java:82)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.xml.XMLModule.parse(XMLModule.java:68)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient.getResponseXML(TiHTTPClient.java:700)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.HTTPClientProxy.getResponseXML(HTTPClientProxy.java:107)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeCallProperty(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.callProperty(V8Object.java:73)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1121)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
[ERROR] :  TiHttpClient:    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:112)
```

The problem is at the start of `onload` method: the error returns after `Titanium.API.info("Start onload");`

Seems is a problem about JSON structure, but i've tried to validate it, and it's ok.

In `index.js` i've used the same mode lo login and i've no problem.

**EDIT:** i've cleaned the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

It's not a problem of code that expects an XML: the output it's misleading.

The first message says

```
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at undefined:1: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

where after "token" there is a space!!!
If i print in console every characters of the string passed by `this.responseText` i can see two spaces: one at start and one at the end.
The first space causes the error in the parsing. The second space it's irrelevant, because it's at the end.

It's very strange because in the other js, `index.js`, where i've used the same iter, the string passed by `this.responseText` doesn't has the space at the start, but has two spaces at the end. However the spaces at the end are irrelevant, so in this case i had not problem with the call.

So with a cicle i take the index of `{` in my string, and then i used the string without the spaces at the start.

```
createReq.onload = function() {
var response = this.responseText;
var i;
for ( i=0; i < this.responseText.length; i++) {
  if (this.responseText[i] == "{")
    break;
};

response = response.slice(i,response.length);
resultReg = JSON.parse(response);

if (resultReg.registered==false) {
// the rest of code
// .....
```

I've choosen this solution because seems that the spaces are put in casually.
It's probably that there is some problems with the managment of the response with HTTPClient. I think that i'll contact also Appcelerator.

Anyway now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Spot the difference:

1) You're sending JSON

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

2) The code is expecting XML:

```
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at undefined:1: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token
[ERROR] :  XMLModule: (KrollRuntimeThread) [46894,49752] Error parsing XML
                                                                       ^^^
```

and

```
[ERROR] :  XMLModule: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token  (position:TEXT {"regi
                          ^^^^^^^---xml parser
                                                            trying to handle JSON  ---^^^^^^
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm agree, but i dont understand why the code is expecting XML! :(

Comment: The problem doesn't is that. There is a space more.